# WPF mouse hover canvas

Tags: wpf, xaml, hover

i could not find answers on SO anywhere - how do i make hover effect for each "item"

i want that when i hover over canvas (data template, positioned inside grid) to change color on both rectangles that are inside canvas - only place where IsMouseOver works is where i set ContentPresenter, and there i can change size of Grid, and thats all. I cannot get IsMouseOver on canvas to change color of rectangles inside. Anyhow, i am just begginer, so, i know something is wrong, ContentPresenter maybe is the one that takes style trigger, i just do not know how to fix this.

```
    <Border Background="#1C222E">
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="SeatsBox">
            <Viewbox.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0"/>
            </Viewbox.RenderTransform>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Seats}" Name="SeatsItems">
                <ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform  X="0" Y="0" />
                </ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid local:GridHelpers.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" local:GridHelpers.ColumnCount="{Binding ColumnCount}" ShowGridLines="False" Background="#1C222E" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowEx}" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColumnEx}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="60"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
                                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Canvas}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Style.Resources>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Canvas Width="30" Height="30" Margin="4" Background="Transparent" Tag="{Binding ID}">
                            <Rectangle Name="RecTop" Canvas.Top="4" Canvas.Left="1" Width="28" Height="18" Fill="#5D606D" Stroke="#5D606D" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"></Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle Name="RecBot" Canvas.Top="23" Canvas.Left="1" Width="28" Height="7" Fill="#5D606D" Stroke="#5D606D" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"></Rectangle>
                            <!-- <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Column}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  /> -->
                        </Canvas>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Taken">
                                <Setter TargetName="RecTop" Property="Stroke" Value="#2E3441" />
                                <Setter TargetName="RecTop" Property="Fill" Value="#2E3441" />
                                <Setter TargetName="RecBot" Property="Stroke" Value="#2E3441" />
                                <Setter TargetName="RecBot" Property="Fill" Value="#2E3441" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Reserved">
                                <Setter TargetName="RecTop" Property="Stroke" Value="#5D606D" />
                                <Setter TargetName="RecBot" Property="Stroke" Value="#5D606D" />
                                <Setter TargetName="RecTop" Property="Fill" Value="Transparent" />
                                <Setter TargetName="RecBot" Property="Fill" Value="Transparent" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Broken">
                                <Setter TargetName="RecTop" Property="Stroke" Value="#1885FF" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Viewbox>
    </Border>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've actually already done it properly, the problem is that you're setting `Fill` explicitly in the Rectangle declarations:

```
<Rectangle ... Fill="#5D606D" ...></Rectangle>
<Rectangle ... Fill="#5D606D" ...></Rectangle>
```

Those fields have precedence over what you've set in your style, remove them and your code works fine.

Comment: Are you sure? Nothing happens when i remove it. Actually, nothing happens on the part style.resources xtype rectangle. Not even width is changed.

Comment: Looking at it again I realize I didn't add a `Status` field to my view model, so none of those DataTemplate triggers were being set. Testing it now I can see that they too are overriding the style, so try removing those as well. (If you want that behavior then you'll need to put the triggers in the style rather than the DataTemplate itself, post back here if you get stuck implementing that).

Comment: ok, it's working now, great, thank you, i did not know that it's like in css (element style over style sheet)